# Automating extraction in power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have been using the following code in Power Query to get the comments for a given objectid (an objectid is the unique id of a status/post/photo/video)

> let
>       Source = Facebook.Graph("https://graph.facebook.com/123131/comments") in
>       Source

Now I have to do this for around 100 objects (I have the objectids of these).

I tried writing a function for the same:

> let
>
> allcomments.results= (odid) => let
>
> Source = Facebook.Graph("https://graph.facebook.com/"&obid&"/comments") in
>
> Source,
>   obid= Table.FromRows({{"121"},{"797"}},{"obid"} in
>
> obid

I have used only 2 object ids here but I guess you can get the jist of what I am trying to do.

Could anyone help me and explain what is wrong with the above code and what am I doing wrong, how to proceed with this?

Comment: Any takers? Would really appreciate some help here

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an error

o**b**id and o**d**id - are different variables. So you try to use a Table instead of Text. Fixed code:

```
let
    allcomments.results = (odid) =>
    let
        Source = Facebook.Graph("https://graph.facebook.com/"&odid&"/comments")
    in
        Source,

    obid = Table.FromRows({{"121"},{"797"}},{"obid"}),
    add_column = Table.AddColumn(obid, "Custom", each allcomments.results([obid]))
in
    add_column
```

## An example with list of values

Insert a table into sheet, name it "excel_table_on_sheet". Name column "obids" and fill it with list of ids. Replace this line in code above

```
obid = Table.FromRows({{"121"},{"797"}},{"obid"}),
```

with this line

```
obid = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="excel_table_on_sheet"]}[Content][obids_column],
```